# Did vs. past perfect and present perfect continuous

Tags: tense, verbs

In a test question:

> How long ___ in Spain before you came here?

Choices are:

a. Did you live
b. Have you lived
c. Have you been living

Accordingly, the answer is a.
Isn't it suppose to be c?

Comment: Why do you think it is supposed to be (c)? Why not (a) or (b)?

Answer (score 1):

"How long ___ in Spain before you came here?"

---

"How long **did you live** in Spain before you came here?"

This answer is correct. Why? The question includes the words "before you came here," meaning that whoever the person is asking no longer lives in Spain. The answer "did" is past tense and indicates that the person no longer lives in Spain.

"Have you lived" is present perfect, indicating that the person still lives in Spain. However, the person can not still be living in Spain because they have moved to "here," as the speaker suggests.

"Have you been living" is perfect progressive, also indicating that the person still lives in Spain. This answer cannot be correct for the same reason as "have you lived."

Answer (score 0):

> How long ___ in Spain before you came here?

'did you live'  would be a preferred option for a US English speaker.

However, in British English, the correct option would be none of the ones given, but the Past Perfect tense: 'had you been living / had you lived'. The reason is that living in Spain is an action previous to coming here. American English speakers do not tend to use perfect tenses.